# Inhouse PC Remote Control Software

Tags: windows-8, remote-access, lan, remote-desktop

I need a software similar to TeamViewer. However, the computer that I will control is in the next room (two desktops).

I do not want to go back and forth between two rooms.

Why I don't want to use TeamViewer? Because I do not want to mess up with the quota. Two computers are connected to the same router/modem. Is there a software available that enables remote desktop control without connecting to a server?

OS: Windows 8.1 for both PCs.

Comment: There is. Still it might help to mention the OS(es) running on the computer(s), to give the best recommendations for those :)

Comment: @Izzy oops, I forgot to mention :) Windows 8.1

Comment: Hm, why does the built-in "Remote Desktop" ([RDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services)) not fit? Apart from that: [Comparison of remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) should be a good starter (I'm from the Linux fraction, so I cannot give a good Windows recommendation – all windows I have are for light and fresh air only ;)

Comment: Depends on just what version of Windows 8.1 you are using. Only the Pro or Enterprise versions can host Remote Desktop connection.

Comment: Does it need to be gratis? If not, what is your budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be quick to dismiss [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). It can also work on a local network. All you need to do is toggle one setting, and allow it through the firewall.

[image]

From [this FAQ](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx):

> You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network directly by using IP addresses or computer names. By default this feature is deactivated because software firewalls may open an acceptance dialog when configured this way.
>
> To activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer full version and Host module:
>
> 1. In the menu click on Extras and then on Options
> 2. On the General tab activate Accept incoming LAN connections
>
> When selecting accept exclusively it will display the IP-address of the computer in the ID-field.
>
> A connection can now be established using the IP-address or alternatively using the host name.